# A bijective function and a convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $f:\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}\to \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ be a bijective function and $x_n=\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}$, which converges. Prove that $x_n \to 1$.

Since $f$ is bijective, there is a unique sequence $(a_n)$, consisting of distinct natural numbers such that $f(a_n)=n$. But $a_n \to \infty$. And so $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(a_n+1)}{f(a_n)}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(a_n+1)}{n}$$ which almost leads to the result. Is there another path I might have taken?

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim_n x_n<1$, for $n$ larger than some  $N$, $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}<1$, hence $f(n)$ decreases, and must converge to some $a>0$. But then $\lim_n \frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}= 1$, a contradiction.

If $\lim_n x_n >1$, for $n$ larger than some  $N$, $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}>1$, hence $f(n)$ increases strictly. Since $f$ is bijective, this forces $f(n+1)-f(n)=1$ for $n$ larger than some $N'$. Then $f(N'+n)=n+f(N')$ for all $n\geq 0$, hence $\lim_n \frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}= 1$, a contradiction.

Comment: How to show that it converges in the first place?

Comment: @mechanodroid it's supposed to converge in the statement of the problem ... OP asks to prove that the limit is $1$.

Comment: I know, I'm wondering how to prove it (if it indeed holds in general).